# Mock website - having trouble with responsive layout; muddles up when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, web

I am doing a mock website for learning but I am struggling understanding certain concepts. At the moment it is particularly to do with the responsiveness of the website. I am not sure I have done the layout wrong or just haven't included the key code.

If anyone wouldn't mind just has a quick look at what I have so far, please?

Thank you!

```
    body {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        background-size: cover;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #header_main {

        font-family:'Jacques Francois Shadow';
        color: #111;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px; 
        padding-bottom: 35px; 
        padding-top: 5px; 
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #708090;
        text-decoration: underline; 
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100%; 
        margin-top: -40px; 
        background-color:#DCDCDC; 

    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #708090;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)  
    }


    li a { 
        float: right;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover{
        background-color: black;
        color: #FF8C00; 
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #FF8C00;
        color: black;
    }

    #top_side {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        background-color:#FF8C00;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)  
    }

    #middle_head {
        width: 520px; 
        text-align: center; 
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Jacques Francois Shadow';
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #708090;
        text-decoration: underline;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-width: 1px; 
        margin-top: 80px; 
        margin-left: 700px; 
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #708090;
    }

    #img_1 {
        width: 900px;
        height: 500px; 
        margin-left: 110px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        border-style: solid; 
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px; 
        border-radius: 5px; 
    }

    #header_1 {
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 20px; 
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px; 
        font-family: 'Jacques Francois Shadow';
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #708090;
    }

    #left_side {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 60px; 
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10px; 
        margin-top: 100px;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 5px; 
        border-width: 1px; 
    }

    #header_2 {
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 20px; 
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px; 
        font-family: 'Jacques Francois Shadow';
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #708090;
    }

    #right_side {
        float: right;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;  
        padding: 10px; 
        margin-right: 80px; 
        margin-top: 100px;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 5px; 
        border-width: 1px; 

    }

    footer {
        margin-top: 100px;
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:#708090;
        opacity: 0.4;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en"> 

        <head>

            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jacques Francois Shadow' rel='stylesheet'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title>Crafty Photography | Home</title>    
        </head>

    <body>

        <header id="header_main">
            <h1>Crafty Photography | Home</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="top_side"></div>

        <div id="middle_head"> 
            <h2>Welcome to Crafty Photography</h2>
        </div> 

        <div id="left_side"> 
            <h2 id="header_1">Anyone is welcome here!</h2> 
            <p>Here at Crafty Photography we love to just take pictures. It can be just 
            of you in a beautiful scene. Or it can be of your family. We will do cater the 
            session to your specifications. Nothing is impossible. So have a look around and 
            see what takes your fancy!</p>
        </div>


        <div id="right_side"> 
            <h2 id="header_2"> We love to take your photo!</h2> 
            <p> Here at Crafty Photography we love to just take pictures. It can be just 
            of you in a beautiful scene. Or it can be of your family. We will do cater the 
            session to your specifications. Nothing is impossible. So have a look around and 
            see what takes your fancy! </p>
        </div>

        <img id="img_1" src="images/img_woman.jpg" alt="Womam with Camera">

        <footer>
            <p>Crafty Photography Copyright 2020</p> 
        </footer>

    </body>

    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. For responsiveness you need to write your responsive css in specific media queries.
You can learn about media queries on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).
Although I use this media query which supports every device. You can use this

```css
/* XL Device :1200px. 1170 */
@media screen and (min-width: 1201) {}

/* LG Device :992px. 970px */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {}

/* MD Device :768px. 750px */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

/* Mobile Layout: 320px. 300px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Wide Mobile Layout: 480px. 450px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}
```

Comment: I see. I hadn't gone through this yet. Thank you for being helpful. I just had one question, do I add these @media to the body or as a container? And would this help with resizing the browser issue? Thanks heaps!

Comment: so when i resize the browser for example, the heading overlaps the nav bar, ive tried using a position but it pretty much does this across the board, nothing stays in place.

Comment: Use these media queries on css file